# What is the issue with the below SQLite statement throwing exception: Table TABLE_NAME has no column named COLUMN_NAME

Tags: android, sqlite

Before posting this question I have went through the following post:

[Exception "table.... has no column named...."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197396/exception-table-has-no-column-named)

and I tried reinstalling the application but its throwing an exception stating that the column uid_name is not there! whats the error here?

I have a database class in which I have the following functions:

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "og_nid";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "og_title";
private static final String KEY_UID = "og_uid";
private static final String KEY_UID_NAME = "uid_name";

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_SURVEYS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SURVEYS + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_UID + " TEXT, " + KEY_UID_NAME + "TEXT "+ ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_SURVEYS_TABLE);
        }
void addSurvey(Survey survey) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        this.onCreate(db);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, survey.get_id()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, survey.get_title());
        values.put(KEY_UID, survey.get_uid());
        values.put(KEY_UID_NAME, survey.get_name());
        // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_SURVEYS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_SURVEYS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SURVEYS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT, " + KEY_UID_NAME + " TEXT "+ ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SURVEYS_TABLE);
    }
```

Your problem is

> KEY_UID_NAME + "TEXT "+ ")"

Give space before text
use this

> KEY_UID_NAME + " TEXT "+ ")"

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one, it was hard to notice that.....may I how did you analyze that ? I mean what do you look for when doing that... when you write a create table stmt ...

Comment: can you please tell me more extactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Put a space here(and of course reinstall or increase the database version):

```
...+ KEY_UID + " TEXT, " + KEY_UID_NAME + " TEXT "+ ")";// notice the space before the last TEXT constraint
```

Currently your last column's name is `uid_nameTEXT`.